# Summing multivalue field values

Tags: drupal, twig

field_iab_quiz_gov_q3 is a multivalue field of float values.

```
2.1|Network Security Policy
2.2|Security Awareness and Training Policy
2.3|Change Management Policy
2.4|Incident Response Policy
2.5|Remote Access Policy
2.6|Vendor Management Policy
2.7|Password Creation and Management Policy
2.8|Access Control Policy
2.9|Data Retention Policy
```

Each option is a checkbox.

My Views field uses the field key.

twig:

```
{% set weight = 0.07 %}

{{ field_iab_quiz_gov_q3|striptags * weight +2  }}%
```

The output produces a comma separated list of values for each option that was checked like so:
2.147% , 2.154% , 2.161% , 2.168% , 2.175% , 2.182% , 2.189% , 2.196% , 2.203%

I want to create a single score value based on the total value each checked option. If only options 1 and 2 were selected the score would be 4.301% etc.

it would be simple if I knew the keys for each value, but I've been struggling how to find the keys.  I thought I could use the field name + an underscore and a number like so:

field_iab_quiz_gov_q3_0  - this would be the first element in the array?

but it did not work.

I tried various permutations of this and none printed a value:

```
{% set value = content.field_iab_quiz_gov_q3[0] %}

{{% value %}}
```

Thanks for your time and thoughts.